# CSS input checkbox when input is already defined

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having difficulty aligning my checkboxes properly in a form.
I've created a jsfiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vknt8/)
The css defines an input earlier on, but I defined a specific checkbox input near the bottom of the css code. For some reason, it's not working.

Main css:

```
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Added checkbox label and input (not working properly)

```
label {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    right: 60px;
    *overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the style from the id `#msform` to overwrite completely the previous declaration.

```
#msform input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    right: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try playing with it now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding width 100% in label is aligning them

```
label {
float: left;
display: block;
padding-left: 15px;
width:100%;
}
```